# Display <ul> tags in wiki

Tags: wiki

I am currently writing a wiki page, but I want to show `<ul></ul>` on the page. I have tried using the supplied `<code></code>` tags, but this doesn't work. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&lt;` and `&gt;` to show `<` and `>`

Answer (score 0):

Easy just use special characters:

```
&lt;ul&gt;

&lt;/ul&gt;
```

<ul>

</ul>